# How to save Modal Data in Database ( Sql workbech ) in Laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-modal

I am a New in web development and Laravel so I am stuck at saving data from Modal it to database (sql workbench). I have model .
Having 2 Database 1. Buffalodata and 2. Buffaloinspectiondata.
Same Modal i am using for Update the data in "Buffalodata" table which is getting done successfully but stuck on adding database "Buffaloinspcectiondata".
Below is the code of the modal.....

```
<!-- The New Monitor Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" tabindex="1" id="newmonitormodal">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl ">
                    <div class="modal-content">

                            <!-- Modal Header -->
                            <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Inspection Data :</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            </div>
                            <form class="form-vertical col-md-12" method="POST" role="form" action="savemonitordata"><input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_field()}}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                                <!-- Modal body -->
                                
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="box-body">
                                            <div class="container-fluid">


                                                <div class="card border border-success elevation-1">
                                                        <div class="card-header">
                                                            <h3 class="card-title"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp;Animal Basic Information</h3>
                                                        </div>  <!-- /.card-header -->

                                                    <div class="card-body">
                                                        <div class="row"> <!-- 1 stform containt start -->
                                                                        
                                                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="fid" disabled> <!-- Getting fid to aceess database -->
                                                                

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="buffaloID">Buffalo ID :</label>
                                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="buffaloID" id="buffaloID">
                                                                    <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="refbuffaloID" id="refbuffaloID">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label>Date of Birth <span class="validate">*</span> :</label>
                                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="birthdate" id="birthdate" onblur="getAge()" data-inputmask-alias="datetime" data-inputmask-inputformat="yyyy/mm/dd" data-mask disabled>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label>Animal Age (in Months) <span class="validate">*</span>:</label>
                                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                                        <input type="text" name="age" class="form-control" id="age" disabled>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="gendertype">Animal Gender <span class="validate">*</span> : </label>
                                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                                        <input type="text"class="form-control" name="gendertype" id="gendertype" disabled>
                                                                    </div>  
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="breedtype">Animal Breed Type <span class="validate">*</span> : </label>
                                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="breedtype" id="breedtype" disabled>
                                                                    </div>  
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="color">Color <span class="validate">*</span>: </label>
                                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                                        <input type="text"select class="form-control" name="color" id="color" disabled>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                        </div>  <!-- Row -->
                                                    </div>  <!-- Card Body -->
                                                </div>  <!-- Card Card-Default -->

                                                <div class="card border border-success elevation-1">
                                                        <div class="card-header">
                                                        <h3 class="card-title"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp;Update Inspection Information</h3>
                                                        </div>  <!-- /.card-header -->

                                                    <div class="card-body">
                                                        <div class="row"> <!-- 1 stform containt start -->

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="weight">Weight (Kgs) <span class="validate">*</span>: </label>
                                                                    <input type="text" name="weight" class="form-control" id="weight" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        
                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="height">Height (Inches) <span class="validate">*</span> : </label>
                                                                    <input type="text" name="height" class="form-control" id="height" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="pregnantstatus">Pregnant Status <span class="validate">*</span> : </label>
                                                                    <select class="form-control" name="pregnantstatus" id="pregnantstatus" required>
                                                                        <option value="No" >No</option>
                                                                        <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="previouspregnantnos">No of Pregnent (Previouse Record) <span class="validate">*</span> : </label>
                                                                    <input type="text" name="previouspregnantnos" class="form-control" id="previouspregnantnos" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                        <label for="nextpreagnancydate"> Next Pregnancy Appox Date <span class="validate">*</span> : </label>
                                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                            <input type="text" name="nextpreagnancydate" class="form-control" id="nextpreagnancydate" data-inputmask-alias="datetime" data-inputmask-inputformat="yyyy/mm/dd" data-mask>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="avgmilk">Milk Per Day (Ltrs.) <span class="validate">*</span> : </label>
                                                                    <input type="text" name="avgmilk" class="form-control" id="avgmilk" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="previousvaccinedone">Previous Vaccine Done <span class="validate">*</span> : </label>
                                                                    <select class="form-control" name="previousvaccinedone" id="previousvaccinedone" required>
                                                                        <option value="No" >No</option>
                                                                        <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="healthstatus">Health Status <span class="validate">*</span> : </label>
                                                                    <select class="form-control" name="healthstatus"id="healthstatus" required>
                                                                        <option value="Healthy">Healthy</option>
                                                                        <option value="Good">Good</option>
                                                                        <option value="Need Attention">Need Attention</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                        </div>  <!-- Row -->
                                                    </div>  <!-- Card Body -->
                                                </div>  <!-- Card Card-Default -->

                                                <!-- /.Third Row Started -->
                                                <div class="card border border-success elevation-1">
                                                    <div class="card-header">
                                                        <h3 class="card-title"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp;Animal Vaccination Information</h3>
                                                    </div>  <!-- /.card-header -->

                                                    <div class="card-body">
                                                        <div class="row">

                                                            <!-- 1 stform containt start -->
                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="bdv">BDV - ( 60 Days ) : </label>
                                                                    <select class="form-control" name="bdv" id="bdv" required>
                                                                        <option value="No">No</option>
                                                                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                                                
                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="bvd">BVD - ( 90 Days ) : </label>
                                                                    <select class="form-control" name="bvd" id="bvd" required>
                                                                        <option value="No">No</option>
                                                                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="pi3">PI3 - ( 120 Days ) : </label>
                                                                    <select class="form-control" name="pi3" id="pi3" required>
                                                                        <option value="No">No</option>
                                                                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="brsv">BRSV - ( 365 Days ) : </label>
                                                                    <select class="form-control" name="brsv" id="brsv" required>
                                                                        <option value="No">No</option>
                                                                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="vitamina">Vitamin A - ( 60 Days ) : </label>
                                                                    <select class="form-control" name="vitamina" id="vitamina" required>
                                                                        <option value="No">No</option>
                                                                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="anthrax">Anthrax - ( 120 Days ) : </label>
                                                                    <select class="form-control" name="anthrax" id="anthrax" required>
                                                                        <option value="No">No</option>
                                                                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>  <!-- /.card-body --> <!-- 3rdform containt end -->

                                                <!-- /.Fourth Row Started -->
                                                <div class="card card-default border border-success bg-white">
                                                    <div class="card-header">
                                                        <h3 class="card-title"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp;Animal Inspection Information</h3>
                                                    </div>  <!-- /.card-header -->

                                                    <div class="card-body">
                                                        <div class="row">

                                                            <!-- 2 stform containt start -->
                                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="inspectiondate">Inspection Date : </label>
                                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                                        <div class="input-group-prepend" >
                                                                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                            <input type="text" name="inspectiondate" class="form-control" id="inspectiondate" value="{{ date('Y/m/d') }}">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="inspectionby">Inspection Done By <span class="validate">*</span>: </label>
                                                                    <input type="text" name="inspectionby" class="form-control" id="inspectionby" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                                                
                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="inspection">Inspection Done : </label>
                                                                    <select class="form-control" name="inspection" id="inspection" required>
                                                                        <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                                                        <option value="Not Done">Not Done</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="weeklytika">Weekly Tikka : </label>
                                                                    <select class="form-control" name="weeklytika" id="weeklytika" required>
                                                                        <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                                                        <option value="Not Done">Not Done</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="monthlytika">Monthly Tikka : </label>
                                                                    <select class="form-control" name="monthlytika" id="monthlytika" required>
                                                                        <option value="Done">Done</option>
                                                                        <option value="Not Done">Not Done</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            
                                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="inspectionnote">Remark <span class="validate">*</span>: </label>
                                                                    <input type="text" name="inspectionnote" class="form-control" id="inspectionnote" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>  <!-- /.card-body --> <!-- Fourth Row containt end -->


                                            </div>  <!-- container-fluid -->
                                        </div>      <!-- Box-body -->
                                    </div>  <!-- modal-body -->
                                
                            
                                
                                    <!-- Modal footer -->
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="submit"class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">
                                                <span id="footer_new_monitor_button" class='glyphicon glyphicon'> Update </span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
                                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'> Close </span>
                                            </button>
                                    </div>

                            </form>
                    </div>  <!-- modal-content -->
                </div>  <!-- modal-dialog -->
            </div>

        <!-- End of New Monitor Modal -->
```

this is my Controller...

```
public function updatemonitorData(Request $req) 
        {
            //dd($req);
            $data = buffalodata::find($req->id);
                
                
                $data->pregnant             = $req->get('pregnantstatus');
                $data->avgmilk              = $req->get('avgmilk');
                $data->health               = $req->get('healthstatus');
                $data->weight               = $req->get('weight');
                $data->height               = $req->get('height');
                $data->previouspregnantnos  = $req->get('previouspregnantnos');
                $data->nextpreagnancydate   = $req->get('nextpreagnancydate');
                $data->previousvaccinedone  = $req->get('previousvaccinedone');

                $data->bdv                  = $req->get('bdv');
                $data->bvd                  = $req->get('bvd');
                $data->pi3                  = $req->get('pi3');
                $data->brsv                 = $req->get('brsv');
                $data->vitamina             = $req->get('vitamina');
                $data->anthrax              = $req->get('anthrax');

                $data->inspectiondate       = $req->get('inspectiondate');
                $data->inspection           = $req->get('inspection');
                $data->weeklytika           = $req->get('weeklytika');
                $data->monthlytika          = $req->get('monthlytika');
                $data->inspectionnote       = $req->get('inspectionnote');
                $data->inspectionby         = $req->get('inspectionby');
                
            $data->save ();

                
            return response()->json( $data );

        }

        public function addmonitorData(Request $req) 
        {
        
            $addinspectiondata = new Buffalomonitor;
            

                $addinspectiondata->buffaloID               = $req->refbuffaloID;
                $addinspectiondata->inspectiondate          = $req->inspectiondate;
                $addinspectiondata->inspection              = $req->inspection;
                $addinspectiondata->pregnant                = $req->pregnantstatus;
                $addinspectiondata->weeklytika              = $req->weeklytika;
                $addinspectiondata->monthlytika             = $req->monthlytika;
                $addinspectiondata->inspectionnote          = $req->inspectionnote;
                $addinspectiondata->inspectionby            = $req->inspectionby;


            $addinspectiondata-> save ();
            return response()->json( $addinspectiondata );
            //return redirect('/buffalo-details');
    
        }
```

web.php file =

```
Route:: post('/updatemonitorData', 'App\Http\Controllers\BuffalomonitorController@updatemonitorData')
->name('updatemonitorData');
     
Route:: post('savemonitordata', 'App\Http\Controllers\BuffalomonitorController@addmonitorData')
->name('savemonitordata');
```